# A service is failing to start on permissions denied--which files is it failing on?

Tags: permissions, suse

I'm attempting to start a service that our company created. In one particular environment, it's failing to start on three "permission denied" errors. I'm not sure which files it is failing on, so I would like to log all permissions-related errors while I attempt to start the daemon.

I've found [auditd](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html), but I've been unable to place a watch on the whole disk for specifically permissions-related errors. What is the best way to audit all permissions-related errors?

Comment: If you created the service, why not install a debug version that does some more explicit error catching and tells you which files it tries to open at every step? The `-vvv` flag was invented for a reason. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) to view all filesystem activity of the processes related to the daemon, and see which ones fail when the permission denied errors appear.

If the error comes from a shell script that starts the service, you can run `sh -x /path/to/startup/script` (or `bash -x /path/to/startup/script` if the script begins with `#!/bin/bash`) and the shell will print each line as it executes it.

Comment: Just start the process under strace and stuff to output somewhere (it tends to be _large_). Make sure strace follows children processes too. Later you can look for calls to open and such, asn see which ones fail.

Comment: I've expanded on your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can try starting your service using `strace` and filter the output only to file-related operations. To see all children processes started by the service I suggest you try to start it with the following options:

```
strace -e trace=file -f /etc/init.d/your-service-startup-script start
```

This will produce a lot of output, so you can either forward it to a file using `-o <log filename>` after `strace` or pipe it through `grep`:

```
strace -e trace=file -f /etc/init.d/your-service-rc-script start 2>&1 | grep 'EACCES'
```

This will display only file system calls that fail due to insufficient privileges (Permission denied). `2>&1` is necessary to redirect `strace`'s `stderr` file descriptor to `stdout` for `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

Check file permissions to run. Try:

chmod 7xx [scriptFile].

Also, ensure the file owner is the correct. Try:

chown group:user [scriptFile]